# Server side pagination using Angular 6 Table/Grid and a web api

Tags: angular, pagination, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web api that accepts GET requests in the following way

https://myapi.net/api/childinfo/getallchildinfo/pagesize/pagenumber

This returns an array of json objects like this:

```
 [  
       {  
          "child":{  
             "id":2832,
             "childId":19979,
             "motherId":20072,
             "guardianId":0,
             "fatherId":19549,
             "childFirstName":"Hapan",
             "childMiddleName":"Victoria Sue",
             "childLastName":"Lafromboise",

          },
          "mother":{  
             "id":3274,
             "motherId":20072,
             "motherFirstName":"Chasity",
             "motherMiddleName":null,
             "motherLastName":"Dumarce",

          },
          "father":{  
             "id":2738,
             "fatherId":19549,
             "fatherFirstName":"gary",
             "fatherMiddleName":null,
             "fatherLastName":"Lafromboise",

          },
          "guardian":null
       },
       {  
          "child":{  
             "id":2831,
             "childId":19978,
             "motherId":20071,
             "guardianId":0,
             "fatherId":19548,
             "childFirstName":"Dale",
             "childMiddleName":"Michael Austin",
             "childLastName":"Palmier",       
          },
          "mother":{  
             "id":3273,
             "motherId":20071,
             "motherFirstName":"Glenna",
             "motherMiddleName":null,
             "motherLastName":"Goodsell",
               },
          "father":{  
             "id":2737,
             "fatherId":19548,
             "fatherFirstName":"WILLIAM",
             "fatherMiddleName":null,
             "fatherLastName":"PALMIER",

          },
          "guardian":null
       },
       {  
          "child":{  
             "id":2830,
             "childId":19977,
             "motherId":20070,
             "guardianId":0,
             "fatherId":19547,
             "childFirstName":"Jahna",
             "childMiddleName":null,
             "childLastName":"Grimm",

          },
          "mother":{  
             "id":3272,
             "motherId":20070,
         "motherFirstName":"Casey",
         "motherMiddleName":null,
         "motherLastName":"Miller",

      },
      "father":{  
         "id":2736,
         "fatherId":19547,
         "fatherFirstName":"John",
         "fatherMiddleName":null,
         "fatherLastName":"Grimm",

      },
      "guardian":null
   }
]
```

There are many examples online where the pagination is done client side, but this is not an option for me. What would be the simplest Table/Grid option where I can implement server side pagination as shown above ?

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the angular material table?

Look at the example titled [Table retrieving data through HTTP](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)